# Google's Load Balancer returning 502 errors with "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client" message and IIS

Tags: iis, google-cloud-platform

We are stumped on this issue and need some assistance. We are running what we believe to be a fairly straightforward configuration in GCP (Google Cloud Platform) for load balancing, and we keep experiencing random "502" errors. Digging into the logs for these, we see a reason given of "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client". I cannot figure out how to reproduce these errors myself. I'm seeing them in the GCP logs and need to diagnose why they're happening.

Here's the moving pieces:

- GCP instance group, named "test-web"

  - Instance group members consist of two Windows Server Core VMs, named "test-web-1" and "test-web-2".
- GCP Load balancer named "test-web-map", with it's backend pointed at the "test-web" instance group.

  - Balancing mode is set to 80% max CPU. Capacity 100%. Timeout is set to 600 seconds.

Our two Windows Server Core VMs are standard GCP images, except for hosting a basic web app via IIS. We've configured IIS to have a connection timeout value of 620 seconds; 20 seconds greater than the backend timeout.

Checking the IIS logs when a 502 happens, I do not see the request even reach the web server.

We're stumped and out of ideas here. Anyone else encounter strange issues with IIS and GCP with Load Balancing and Instance Groups?

Comment: The Load Balancer failed to establish a connection with the backend. This could mean that the service running on the backend is not listening on the port defined in the backend service. Refer to the [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#unexplained_502_errors) for more information.

To investigate further, Kindly provide TCP dumps/wireshark  logs to investigate the issue further .

Comment: Could you please update regarding your issue.

Comment: 502 errors are written into Windows HTTP logs, not IIS logs.